# Presto - how to perform correlations on between all columns in one query

Tags: sql, hive, presto, amazon-athena

I have a table in the following format:

```
A   B   C   D 
7   7   2   12
2   2   3   4
2   2   2   4
2   2   2   3
5   5   2   7
```

I would like to calculate correlations between each of the columns using the build-in correlation function (https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html  corr(y, x) → double)

I could run over all the columns and perform the corr calculation each time with:
`select corr(A,B) from table`
but I would like to reduce the number of times I access presto and run it in one query if its possible.

Would it be possible to get as a result the column names that pass a certain threshold or at least the correlation scores between all possible combinations in one query?

Thanks.

Comment: Correlation involves two series of data (here, two columns). How would you define the correlation *between each of the columns*?

Comment: Maybe I should clarify, I would like to get the correlation matrix between all the column combinations in one query (A with B, A with C, A with D, B with C and etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to calculate correlations between each of the columns

Correlation involves two series of data (in SQL, two columns). So I understand your question as: how to compute the correlation for each and every possible combination of columns in the table. That would look like:

```
select
    corr(a, b) corr_a_b,
    corr(a, c) corr_a_c,
    corr(a, d) corr_a_d,
    corr(b, c) corr_b_c,
    corr(b, d) corr_c_d,
    corr(c, d) corr_c_d
from mytable
```

Comment: This is a possible solution, yet that is unusable for tables with 100-200 columns.

Comment: @Andreyn: what you describe cannot be achieved in pure SQL. You would need dynamic SQL for this (ie dynamically construct the query string, then execute it).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lateral join to unpivot the table, then a self join and aggregation:

```
with v as (
      select v.*, t.id
      from (select t.*,
                   row_number() over (order by a) as id
            from t
           ) t cross join lateral
           (values ('a', a), ('b', b), ('c', c), ('d', d)
           ) v(col, val)
     )
select v1.col, v2.col, corr(v1.val, v2.val)
from v v1 join
     v v2
     on v1.id = v2.id and v1.which < v2.which
group by v1.col, v2.col;
```

The `row_number()` is only to generate a unique id for each row, which is then used for the self-join.  You may already have a column with this information, so that might not be necessary.